# Как сделать сортировку в jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jade

Есть объект json (приходит с сервера). Можно ли его отсортировать по order?
Вот сам объект

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "тест",
    "active": true,
    "slides": [
      {
        "imgUrl": "/images/test_slide-1.jpg",
        "order": 3
      },
      {
        "imgUrl": "/images/test_slide-2.jpg",
        "order": 2
      },
      {
        "imgUrl": "/images/test_slide-3.jpg",
        "order": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

Как вставить массив `slides` с сортировкой по `order`? Вот код `jade`, слайды подставляются, но без сортировки

```
.slides
  - function sortNumber (a, b) {return a - b};
  each p in data
    - if (p.active)
      - var length = p.slides.length
      - for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
          - console.log(p.slides[i].order);
          section(data-background=p.slides[i].imgUrl)
```

P.S. `data`, объект выше

Comment: может лучше на фронте с помощью js сортировать и вставлять, чем в jade

Comment: с помощью js сортировать так - var slides = json.slides.sort( function( a, b ){ return a.order - b.order; } );